# BigQuery's support of JSON array for import

Tags: json, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a list of items stored in JSON. Currently, it seems that BigQuery doesn't support JSON array. I have the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "purchaseId": "f7c67e39-5382-4d08-a308-0e4657143c44",
        "platform": "googleplay",
        "createdAt": 1364226047214,
        "type": "currency",
        "purchaseDate": 1364225968000,
        "updatedAt": 1364226052634
    },
    {
        "purchaseId": "f7c67e39-5382-4d08-a308-0e4657143c44",
        "platform": "googleplay",
        "createdAt": 1364226047214,
        "type": "currency",
        "purchaseDate": 1364225968000,
        "updatedAt": 1364226052634
    },
    {
        "purchaseId": "f7c67e39-5382-4d08-a308-0e4657143c44",
        "platform": "googleplay",
        "createdAt": 1364226047214,
        "type": "currency",
        "purchaseDate": 1364225968000,
        "updatedAt": 1364226052634
    }
]
```

I get the following error:

```
    Line:1 / Column:1, Expected '{' found '['
```

Something like the following would be invalid JSON:

```
    {
        "purchaseId": "f7c67e39-5382-4d08-a308-0e4657143c44",
        "platform": "googleplay",
        "createdAt": 1364226047214,
        "type": "currency",
        "purchaseDate": 1364225968000,
        "updatedAt": 1364226052634
    },
    {
        "purchaseId": "f7c67e39-5382-4d08-a308-0e4657143c44",
        "platform": "googleplay",
        "createdAt": 1364226047214,
        "type": "currency",
        "purchaseDate": 1364225968000,
        "updatedAt": 1364226052634
    }
```

So what's the best way to group items in JSON which can then be easily consumed by BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the input technically is invalid JSON. It's called "newline-delimited JSON". Each line must be a self-contained JSON dictionary with a newline at the end. No comma between the lines.